# ios crash [_UIBackgroundTaskInfo fireExpirationHandler]

Tags: ios, crash

Got this crash report from crashlytics, any idea how to decipher this?  I think it's related to some background task that I am doing.  I am using restkit's background continue option.  Crashlytics is also telling me that only 12% of user has the app in focus when this happens.

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib    objc_msgSend + 15
1    UIKit ✭            -[_UIBackgroundTaskInfo fireExpirationHandler] + 48
2    UIKit              -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1288
3    UIKit              -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 54
4    UIKit              _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
5    GraphicsServices   PurpleEventCallback + 882
6    CoreFoundation     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
7    CoreFoundation     __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
8    CoreFoundation     __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
9    CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
10   CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
11   GraphicsServices   GSEventRunModal + 136
12   UIKit              UIApplicationMain + 1080
```